# Setup gevent with Lighttpd, weird stuff

Tags: python, fastcgi, lighttpd, gevent

I have wary odd problem. I configured Lighttpd to pass /test to fastcgi backend.
just added this in config

```
fastcgi.server = ("/test" =>
  ("127.0.0.1" =>
    (
      "host" => "127.0.0.1",
      "port" => 7101,
      "docroot" => "/",
      "check-local" => "disable"
    )
  )
)
```

Now, when i start flup example, and hit 127.0.0.1:80/test everything work fine. Tested uWSGI to, still fine.

flup example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer

def myapp(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello World']

WSGIServer(myapp, bindAddress = ('127.0.0.1',7101)).run()
```

Now, only problem is when I start gevent it won't work. Lighttpd mod_fastcgi says that backend just blocked.

Funny part is when I alter handler to return just string, cause WSGI require iterable, and hit 127.0.0.1:7101 from my browser it work as expected. This should be WSGIServer, how can it work this way?

Here is gevent code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""WSGI server example"""
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer

def app(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    #return ["Hello World", StopIteration]   # this is WSGI test, not working
    return "Hello World"
    # when set like this, frontend :80 still wont work (500 Internal error), 
    # but 127.0.0.1:7101 work like standard http

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(('', 7101), app).serve_forever()
```

Bottom line is , why only gevent wont work in this setup, and both flup and uWSGI are working? Is there some secret setting not mention in official example [here](https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/tip/examples/wsgiserver.py#cl-4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer is not a fcgi server, it's only http server. Your can proxy your requests from lighttpd to gevent as http, or use wsgi.

Comment: Hm, I need fcgi for load balancing. I don't understand, official documentation and examples says it is WSGI server see here https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/tip/examples/wsgiserver.py#cl-4

Comment: I think that it means, that it is server that provides wsgi interface for handlers: environ, start_response, etc.

Comment: If you need gevent and fcgi, you could use uwsgi with gevent-loop.

Answer (score 0):

U can see that flup [here](http://trac.saddi.com/flup/wiki/FlupServers) states it SPEAK FastCGI (**not HTTP**), and uWSGI [here](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) says "Born as a WSGI-only server". 
Now Gevent says [here](http://www.gevent.org/) "Fast WSGI server based on libevent-http", that confused me, but then I try gunicorn, and it steel failed. 
Then i found [here](http://gunicorn.org/) "Gunicorn 'Green Unicorn' is a Python WSGI **HTTP** Server for UNIX". That means that gevent and gunicorn WSGI handlers are HTTP request **not FastCGI**, but ,as Fedor Gogolev said, **for your handlers** they are WSGI servers.

So for **Flup** and **uWSGI** u configure lighttpd (or any other web server) to use **fastcgi** module, but for **gunicorn** and **gevent** u use **proxy** module, and for them u don't have to use frontend at all!If don't have static stuff to serve or other reason u can omit frontend cause **gunicorn** state it is wary fast and stable.